# Compute the cumulative hazard of a time interval

Tags: hazard, integral

I'm a little confused in calculating the cumulative hazard within a time interval.

We know that $H(t)=\int^{t}_{0}h(u)du$, if I have $\Delta t=t_1-t_0$

(1) $H(\Delta t)=\int^{\Delta t}_{0}h(u)du$

(2) $H(\Delta t)=\int^{t_1}_{0}h(u)du-\int^{t_0}_{0}h(u)du$.

Which is the correct one? (1) or (2)?

I felt the (1) may be the correct.

Comment: In which time interval are you interested?  From $0$ to $\Delta t$ or from $t_1$ to $t_0$?

Comment: it is $0<t_0<t_1<T$ and $\Delta t=t_1-t_0$

Comment: You have just named *three* distinct intervals $(0, t_0)$, $(t_0,t_1)$, $(t_1,T)$, and one *duration* ($\Delta t$). Your question has an answer once you can decide which of those you want to accumulate the hazard within.

Comment: Which is the correct one for $H(\Delta t)$? This is my question.

Answer (score 0):

If $h(u)$ doesn't depend on $u$ then (1) has the same value as (2). Otherwise, $H$ is a function of both time interval boundaries rather than just the difference between them.

Comment: Thanks, James. I'm wondering why (1) has the same value as (2) if $h(u)$ doesn't depend on $u$.

Comment: Assuming that $h(u) = C$ take all integrals and see.